# Resilience4j Retry - Memory consumption

Tags: java, resilience4j, resiliency, resilience4j-retry

I am using resilience4j with Spring Boot 2.x
What is the impact of using Retry and circuit breaker modules on memory and cpu?

Also what is the memory impact if I have 2000 events/s incoming each payload around 10Mb and I have kept the wait duration of retry as 15 seconds with exponential backoff multiplier as 2?
I have 8Gb of application memory

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to monitor your application with a profile like VisualVM. Then you can know where is the bottleneck.

One thing that I know that matters is where you create your circuitbreaker instance. In the end there is a collector that remove the instances not used. But in your case it seems to be a good idea to not place the creation of the circuit breaker on the get method like [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker)

```
@Service
public static class DemoControllerService {
    private RestTemplate rest;
    private CircuitBreakerFactory cbFactory;
    public DemoControllerService(RestTemplate rest, CircuitBreakerFactory cbFactory) {
        this.rest = rest;
        this.cbFactory = cbFactory;
    }
    public String slow() {
        return cbFactory.create("slow").run(() -> rest.getForObject("/slow", String.class), throwable -> "fallback");
    }
}
```

But create the circuitbreaker on the constructor.

```
@Service
public class DemoControllerService {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private CircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory;
    private CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker;

    @Autowired
    public DemoControllerService(CircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory) {
        this.circuitBreakerFactory = circuitBreakerFactory;
        this.circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("circuitbreaker");
    }
```

There are also discussions to place one circuitbreaker per [host](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/703). Other thing that you can do is to [remove the instance of the Registry](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-core/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/core/Registry.java#L54) by yourself and not wait for the circuitbreaker component rome it in the future.

```
registry.remove(circuitBreakerName);
```

[Here](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/650) is a discussion also about to clean up the Registry memory.